# Key maping for the seeing_is_believing vim plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to get [seeing_is_believing](https://github.com/JoshCheek/seeing_is_believing/) plugin to work with my vim.

So far I was able to get the key mapping working to annotate to whole file and clear the annotations.

However now I'm stuck with `Mark the current line for annotation` section.

[this is what is in the wiki page](https://github.com/JoshCheek/seeing_is_believing/wiki/Editor-Integration)

[image]

My question is what does this key mappings means, (or how can I read these 
key mappings)

```
" Mark the current line for annotation
nmap <leader>m A # => <Esc>
" Mark the highlighted lines for annotation
vmap <leader>m :norm A # => <Esc>
```

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nmap <leader>m A # => <Esc>
```

Has nothing to do with the plugin, it just Adds a `# =>` at the end of the line if you press `<leader>m`. (See `:h leader`).

The first part of the mapping is the key sequence (`<leader>m`) to initiate the mapping, the second part defienes what it does `A # => <Esc>`
`A` means go to insert mode at the end of the line. In insert mode `# =>` is typed and then go back to normal with `<esc>`

The second mapping `nmap <leader>m A # => <Esc>` does exactly the same, but for every line marked in the visual mode. (see `:h :norm` it does execute the following string as keypresses in the normalmode)